# Multi objective optimization: Ideal vector

Tags: optimization

[image]

I'm going to consider the two problem distinctly.
Now I want to calculate $z_1^{id}$ and $z_2^{id}$ and $x_1^{id}$ and $x_2^{id}$ where

$z_1^{id} = min(x)$

$z_2^{id} = max(y)$

*$z_1^{id}$ is the value of the first objective function when I consider only the first one. $z_2^{id}$ when i consider only the second*

I tried. And I get:

$z_1^{id} = 0 $

$z_2^{id} = 2 $

But I cannot figure out **which is the optimal $x_1$ and $x_2$ ??** Because in the objective function and I have either $x$ or $y$, not both.

[image]

Comment: What is your objective function? This is not clear in you post. And what is $z_1^{id}$ and so on?

Comment: $z_1^{id}$ is the value of the first objective function when I consider only the first one. $z_2^{id}$ when i consider only the second